# Oracle throws ORA-00911 invalid character error while executing a query generated by entity framework 6.0

Tags: sql, oracle, entity-framework, oracle11g, ora-00911

I'm having problems with the query below which is generated by Entity Framewrok 6.0. When I remove where clause query is being executed well. But I cant see the problem on where clause. Can you please help me?

```
{SELECT 
"Extent1"."ID" AS "ID", 
"Extent1"."STATECODE" AS "STATECODE", 
"Extent1"."FIRMAID" AS "FIRMAID", 
"Extent1"."ILID" AS "ILID", 
"Extent1"."ILCEID" AS "ILCEID", 
"Extent1"."PLANTURID" AS "PLANTURID", 
"Extent1"."ETUDTURID" AS "ETUDTURID", 
"Extent1"."ETUDAMACID" AS "ETUDAMACID", 
"Extent1"."DILIMID" AS "DILIMID", 
"Extent1"."ACIKLAMA" AS "ACIKLAMA", 
"Extent1"."BASVURUTARIHI" AS "BASVURUTARIHI", 
"Extent1"."ALAN" AS "ALAN", 
"Extent1"."OLCEK" AS "OLCEK", 
"Extent1"."CREATETIME" AS "CREATETIME", 
"Extent1"."UPDATETIME" AS "UPDATETIME", 
"Extent1"."CREATEUSERID" AS "CREATEUSERID", 
"Extent1"."UPDATEUSERID" AS "UPDATEUSERID", 
"Extent2"."ID" AS "ID1", 
"Extent2"."KOD" AS "KOD", 
"Extent2"."AD" AS "AD", 
"Extent2"."CREATETIME" AS "CREATETIME1", 
"Extent2"."UPDATETIME" AS "UPDATETIME1", 
"Extent2"."CREATEUSERID" AS "CREATEUSERID1", 
"Extent2"."UPDATEUSERID" AS "UPDATEUSERID1", 
"Extent3"."ID" AS "ID2", 
"Extent3"."KOD" AS "KOD1", 
"Extent3"."AD" AS "AD1", 
"Extent3"."PLANTURID" AS "PLANTURID1", 
"Extent3"."CREATETIME" AS "CREATETIME2", 
"Extent3"."UPDATETIME" AS "UPDATETIME2", 
"Extent3"."CREATEUSERID" AS "CREATEUSERID2", 
"Extent3"."UPDATEUSERID" AS "UPDATEUSERID2", 
"Extent4"."ID" AS "ID3", 
"Extent4"."VERGINUMARASI" AS "VERGINUMARASI", 
"Extent4"."EMAIL" AS "EMAIL", 
"Extent4"."FIRMAADI" AS "FIRMAADI", 
"Extent4"."BUROTESCILNUMARASI" AS "BUROTESCILNUMARASI", 
"Extent4"."TELEFON" AS "TELEFON", 
"Extent4"."ADRES" AS "ADRES", 
"Extent4"."ILID" AS "ILID1", 
"Extent4"."ILCEID" AS "ILCEID1", 
"Extent4"."MAHALLEID" AS "MAHALLEID", 
"Extent4"."VERGIDAIRESIID" AS "VERGIDAIRESIID", 
"Extent4"."USERID" AS "USERID", 
"Extent4"."NODEID" AS "NODEID", 
"Extent4"."CREATETIME" AS "CREATETIME3", 
"Extent4"."UPDATETIME" AS "UPDATETIME3", 
"Extent4"."CREATEUSERID" AS "CREATEUSERID3", 
"Extent4"."UPDATEUSERID" AS "UPDATEUSERID3", 
"Extent5"."FEATUREID" AS "FEATUREID", 
"Extent5"."ADI_NUMARASI" AS "ADI_NUMARASI", 
"Extent5"."UAVTKOD" AS "UAVTKOD", 
"Extent6"."FEATUREID" AS "FEATUREID1", 
"Extent6"."ADI_NUMARASI" AS "ADI_NUMARASI1", 
"Extent6"."UAVTKOD" AS "UAVTKOD1", 
"Extent6"."ILKOD" AS "ILKOD", 
"Extent7"."ID" AS "ID4", 
"Extent7"."ENLEM" AS "ENLEM", 
"Extent7"."BOYLAM" AS "BOYLAM", 
"Extent7"."DILIMI" AS "DILIMI", 
"Extent7"."MERIDYEN" AS "MERIDYEN", 
"Extent7"."ILADI" AS "ILADI", 
"Extent7"."ILID" AS "ILID2", 
"Extent8"."ID" AS "ID5", 
"Extent8"."KOD" AS "KOD2", 
"Extent8"."AD" AS "AD2", 
"Extent8"."CREATETIME" AS "CREATETIME4", 
"Extent8"."UPDATETIME" AS "UPDATETIME4", 
"Extent8"."CREATEUSERID" AS "CREATEUSERID4", 
"Extent8"."UPDATEUSERID" AS "UPDATEUSERID4"
FROM        "JEOLOJI"."PROJE" "Extent1"
INNER JOIN "JEOLOJI"."ETUDAMAC" "Extent2" ON "Extent1"."ETUDAMACID" = "Extent2"."ID"
INNER JOIN "JEOLOJI"."ETUDTUR" "Extent3" ON "Extent1"."ETUDTURID" = "Extent3"."ID"
INNER JOIN "JEOLOJI"."FIRMA" "Extent4" ON "Extent1"."FIRMAID" = "Extent4"."ID"
INNER JOIN "JEOLOJI"."IL" "Extent5" ON "Extent1"."ILID" = "Extent5"."FEATUREID"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "JEOLOJI"."ILCE" "Extent6" ON "Extent1"."ILCEID" = "Extent6"."FEATUREID"
INNER JOIN "JEOLOJI"."DILIM" "Extent7" ON "Extent1"."DILIMID" = "Extent7"."ID"
INNER JOIN "JEOLOJI"."PLANTUR" "Extent8" ON "Extent1"."PLANTURID" = "Extent8"."ID"
WHERE ((1 = (CASE WHEN (( NVL(INSTR(LOWER(CASE WHEN ("Extent1"."ACIKLAMA" IS NULL) THEN '' ELSE "Extent1"."ACIKLAMA" END), LOWER('Ma')), 0) ) = 1) THEN 1 WHEN (( NVL(INSTR(LOWER(CASE WHEN ("Extent1"."ACIKLAMA" IS NULL) THEN '' ELSE "Extent1"."ACIKLAMA" END), LOWER('Ma')), 0) ) <> 1) THEN 0 END)) AND (22 <> "Extent1"."FIRMAID"))}
```

Comment: it doesnt give what charachter..only the subject erro?

Comment: The only output is this : ERROR ORA-00911: invalid character

Comment: did u try to run it in oracle window?

Comment: I am assuming the { and } are not actually there in the real query? Try running in sqlplus or similar and see what happens. Also that WHERE clause isn't likely to perform very well when you actually get it to run.

Comment: Isn't this complicated `WHERE ...` clause equivalent to `where lower("Extent1"."ACIKLAMA") like 'ma%' and "Extent1"."FIRMAID" <> 22` ?

Comment: Thats a query generated by entity framework. I have a grid view and query is being generated by the filters of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

We are marking our `string` types in c# with `StringLength` attribute to prevent Entity Framework to create them as `NCLOB` columns on Oracle. Then Entity Framework generates columns with type `nvarchar` for c# propeties marked with `StringLenth` attribute.

In this query the `where` clause works fine with `varchar2` because of the qoutes(as I learned from my Db profession friend.) So I changed the types of the columns and its solved.